# Django Group model not showing up in Django admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I cannot see Django Group model on the admin page. I get an error if I try and register it from the admin.py file saying that Group is already registered.

I cannot see it even if I unregister and register it again.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group)
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Please provide something for us to work on, preferably a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At this point, your question can't be really answered.

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example, as it doesn't cause the same effect for other people. Try to create a new Django project, compare it with your current one and note down all differences that may be significant to your issue. You can then create an example that will allow to reproduce your issue for anyone.

Comment: @GwynBleidD It was an issue of another app changing the admin page and it was listed lowest in INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django by default will display User and Group models on admin page under Authentication and Authorization.

In this case there was an app listed below in the INSTALLED_APPS of project settings that was responsible for not showing Group on admin page as it was unregistering the Group model.

Answer (score 2):

I may run into the same issue *@Django 3.2.12*

I have this in my accounts app

accounts/admin.py

```py
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

**User Profiles** shows under the `ACCOUNTS`,
but the **Group** Link still under `AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION`
instead

Any one see this before? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try importing `from django.contrib.auth.models import User, groups`. Another option is that you have not imported `from django.contrib import admin`, at the moment without seeing any code is the only thing I can think of, I hope it helps you, greetings.

Comment: Added code for my approach with unregistering and registering again since it didn't show up by default

Comment: Finally figured it out. There was another which was listed below in installed apps and it was unregistering it. Thank you.